# left/center/right-align three elements with variable width in container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float, css-grid

I am trying to achieve a HTML layout where items are aligned left/center/right regardless of their variable widths:

```
[[left with variable width]       [centered in parent]                 [right]]
```

I have tried to implement this using "flexbox":

```css
#left{background-color:aqua;}
#center{background-color:lime;}
#right{background-color:yellow;}
#box {background-color:gray;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30em;
  display:flex;
}

/*attempt one
  -> "center" pushed towards "right" by "left" 
  */
#box{justify-content: space-between;}

/*attempt two
  -> items assume same width, each content is left-aligned; 
     "left" wraps/expands along cross-axis (height)
  */
/*#left,#center,#right{flex: 1;}*/

/*attempt three
  -> all items centered with minimum width
  */
/*
#box{justify-content: center ;}
*/

/* align-items / align-self is for cross-axis */
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="left">left expands and pushes center</div>
  <div id="center">center</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

but so far failed to create a simple solution. It probably is possible to use flexbox to create equal columns and then align each content left/center/right with additional containers or style rules.

Other questions have not yet solved my problem, such as [Aligning three elements (left/center/right) inside a container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426507/aligning-three-elements-left-center-right-inside-a-container), which also uses flexbox, but requires same-width elements.

[How to align three divs (left/center/right) for getting in small screen left/right and under them center element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851561/how-to-align-three-divs-left-center-right-for-getting-in-small-screen-left-rig) uses float as an alternative.

The excellent [In CSS Flexbox, why are there no "justify-items" and "justify-self" properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551291/in-css-flexbox-why-are-there-no-justify-items-and-justify-self-properties) shows a few solutions, on of which uses absolute positioning for the center item and `margin:auto;` for the right item.

It seems, that without [`justify-self` for flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32583512/1619432), my goal cannot be realized.

gridlayout (which has justify-self) may be an alternative:

```
#box{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
#left{justify-self:flex-start;}
#center{justify-self:center;}
#right{justify-self:flex-end;}
```

But I might be wrong, so the the questions remaining are:

- can flexbox solve this "cleanly" (without additional child containers/rules)?
- what would be a solution with additional rules (text-align?)
- do I need to turn to floats or gridlayout?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55393886/8620333 ( you will need extra containers)

Comment: ^ if the duplicate is suitable for you I can close the question if you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif If offers one solution, but not all the answers. However, feel free to close, as my question really is quite the same.

Comment: An old question, lots of `float` solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div